# What CPU registers are part of Process Control Block (PCB) in linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, cpu-registers, context-switch

Just wondering what CPU registers are copied into PCB when context switching happens in Linux. Is it different for other Operating Systems like Mac OSX and Windows.

Comment: Linux is open-source.   You can look it up yourself.

Comment: The registers are probably stored in structure `task_struct` or in `pt_regs` structure. Start reading at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h